# PostgreSQL get any value from jsonb object

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I want to get the value of either key 'a' or 'b' if either one exists. If neither exists, I want the value of any key in the map.

Example:

- `'{"a": "aaa", "b": "bbbb", "c": "cccc"}'` should return `aaa`.
- `'{"b": "bbbb", "c": "cccc"}'` should return `bbb`.
- `'{"c": "cccc"}'` should return `cccc`.

Currently I'm doing it like this:
`SELECT COALESCE(o ->> 'a', o ->> 'b', o->> 'c') FROM...`

The problem is that I don't really want to name key 'c' explicitly since there are objects that can have any key.

So how do I achieve the desired effect of "Get value of either 'a' or 'b' if either exists. If neither exists, grab anything that exists."?

I am using postgres 9.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe too long:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"a": "aaa", "b": "bbbb", "c": "cccc"}'::jsonb))
, m as (select j,jsonb_object_keys(j) k from c)
, f as (select * from m where k not in ('a','b') limit 1)
t-# select COALESCE(j ->> 'a', j ->> 'b', j->>k) from f;
 coalesce
----------
 aaa
(1 row)
```

and with no a,b keys:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"a1": "aaa", "b1": "bbbb", "c": "cccc"}'::jsonb))
, m as (select j,jsonb_object_keys(j) k from c)
, f as (select * from m where k not in ('a','b') limit 1)
select COALESCE(j ->> 'a', j ->> 'b', j->>k) from f;
 coalesce
----------
 cccc
(1 row)
```

Idea is to [extract all keys with](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) `jsonb_object_keys` and get the first "random"(because I don't order by anything) (`limit 1`) and then use it for last `coalesce` invariant

Comment: Thank you for that. I wasn't able to find any way to do it. For the current use case this is a bit much but now I know there is a way to do it. My first thought was a simple `o ->> 0` like you do for arrays but that just wasn't to be...